# NumPy array filter optimisation

Tags: python, performance, array, numpy

I've got a filter that I'd like to work out how to optimize. The most basic implementation, using loops is like the following:

```
import numpy as np
nrow = 500
ncol = 500
refArray = np.random.randint( 0,100, (nrow,ncol) )
boundsArray = np.random.randint( 90,95, (2,nrow,ncol) )
window = 31
halfwindow = window/2
result = np.zeros_like(refArray)
## we'll ignore edges for the moment

for i in range(halfwindow, nrow - halfwindow):
    for j in range(halfwindow, ncol - halfwindow):
        window = refArray[ (i-halfwindow):(i+1+halfwindow), (j-halfwindow):(j+1+halfwindow)]
        valid = (window >= boundsArray[0,i,j]) & (window <= boundsArray[1,i,j])
        result[ (i-halfwindow):(i+1+halfwindow), (j-halfwindow):(j+1+halfwindow) ] \
           += valid
```

So, for each location (i,j) in an array, I find a window around this location, and identify all elements which meet a particular requirement, then move on. At each step I count how often element (i,j) has met the requirement.

I'm looking for suggestions on approaches to write this efficiently. I can't see how I can avoid the loops, so I'd consider options like Cython or f2py.

Comment: Are `boundsArray` and `refArray` always random, or would these be specified in production code?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a partial solution:

```
as_strided = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided
def fun2(refArray):
        y = len(range(-halfwindow,halfwindow+1))
        II=slice(halfwindow, nrow - halfwindow)
        bA = boundsArray[:,II,II]
        x=len(range(halfwindow,nrow-halfwindow))
        shape = (x,x) + (y,y)
        strides = refArray.strides
        strides = strides + strides
        print(shape, strides)
        A = as_strided(refArray, shape=shape,strides=strides)
        print(A.shape,(refArray[0,0],refArray[-1,-1]),(A[0,0,0,0],A[-1,-1,-1,-1]))
        valid = (A >= bA[0,:,:,None,None]) & \
             (A <= bA[1,:,:,None,None])
        valid = valid.sum((-2,-1))
        # # valid pts per window
        print(valid.shape)
        return valid
```

It uses `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` to create overlapping windows.  It's an idea that has been presented in several SO answers.

In timing it is 4-5x faster than your iteration.

`A` is a `(470,470,31,31)` view of `refArray`, i.e. 470x470 windows, each 31x31.  And with the `strides` value they overlap.

But it is partial.  `valid.sum()` gives the same values as your `result.sum()`.  So it finds the same total number of 'valid' points. But `valid` (after summing on the 31x31 dimensions) is a (470,470) array, one value for each 'window', and that value is the number of valid points within the window.  It is the equivalent of doing `windows[i-halfwindow,j-halfwindow] = valid.sum()` in your iteration.

I think your `result` is the number of windows in which each point is valid.

I haven't figured out how to map the `(470,470,31,31)` `valid` array back on to the `(500,500)` points.  But I pretty sure there is such a mapping.

---

This is a temporary fix:

```
def fun2(refArray):
        y = len(range(-halfwindow,halfwindow+1))
        II=slice(halfwindow, nrow - halfwindow)
        bA = boundsArray[:,II,II]
        x=len(range(halfwindow,nrow-halfwindow))
        shape = (x,x) + (y,y)
        strides = refArray.strides
        strides = strides + strides
        A = as_strided(refArray, shape=shape,strides=strides)
        valid = (A >= bA[0,:,:,None,None]) & \
             (A <= bA[1,:,:,None,None])
        return valid

def fun3(refArray,valid):
        result = np.zeros_like(refArray)
        n0,n1,n2,n3 = valid.shape
        for i in range(n0):
            for j in range(n1):
                result[ i:(i+n2),j:(j+n3) ] += valid[i,j]
        return result
result = fun3(refArray, fun2(refArray))
```

`fun3` has the same sort of iteration as your code, but there's still a 2x speedup.

While each window has the same number of points, the reverse is not true.  Corner points occur in only one window each.  Middle ones around 900 each.  That may make a pure vectorized numpy solution impossible.